# Is there any way to change one magic item into another with the same properties?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

Is there a spell, ability or skill that will let a player transform one magic item into another?

For example, if I have a [Staff of power](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/staff-of-power) could I transform it into a rapier, with all the same attributes and abilities?

If so, how?

I'm looking for existing rules as opposed to "ask your gm"   using any official WotC rules but not UA.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### No, there is no official feature.

There's not much I can offer as evidence. I've read all the splatbooks several times over and have extensive experience as a player and a DM running *5th Edition*, and I've never come across such a feature. Unfortunately, the best you can do is "ask your DM".

It is worth mentioning that a *wish* spell could possibly do this, but that’s just [“ask your DM” with extra steps.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/185204/62294)

#### The *Dungeon Master's Guide* gives it as an option for DMs to modify magic items.

We do see in the *Dungeon Master's Guide*, in the section "Modifying an Item":

> The easiest way to invent a new item is to tweak an existing one. If a paladin uses a flail as her main weapon, you could change a holy avenger so that it’s a flail instead of a sword. You can turn a ring of the ram into a wand, or a cloak of protection into a circlet of protection, all without altering the item’s properties.

This is the feature you want, but it is strictly DM-facing, so the official rule is, ironically, ask your DM.